# Using woopra analytic for getting stored data back

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics-api

I am new to woopra analytic . So far i have written java script that is sending user activity back to woopra server . This module is working fine.

What i want to do is .
Get data back from woopra server depending upon particular user

For example if user had searched for particular product then i need to
 show on the web site that what user  recently searched.